# python timer could not work for two times

Tags: python

I use python 2.7 in windows 7.
I have used timer
But the timer could only run once.

```
 import threading 

 class BesDldMainWnd(QMainWindow):

     def fun_timer（self）:
          print 1


     def StartAll(self):
          timer = threading.Timer(30, self.fun_timer)         
          timer.start()

m = BesDldMainWnd（）
m.Startall()
time.sleep(30)
m.Startall()
```

I expected the timer run twice, but it run only once.

Comment: Show expected result and actual result

Comment: Read about [This method will raise a RuntimeError if called more than once on the same thread object.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start)

Comment: @ stovfl  how to solve my problem in my case

Comment: @age  I have added those.

Comment: @GetDlgItem ***"I have added those"***: [Edit] your question, you have **indentation errors** and a type in `Startall`. Also Add the output. Unfortunatly can't test with `QMainWindow`, does it work without it.

Comment: bro two things: Python 2 is end-of-life, so just don't use python2. It's very easy to install python3. Secondly, your code doesn't run. e.g. why is there a space: `m = BesDldMainWnd（）` Also your brackets aren't the same as mine, what editor are you using? It's just all super bad.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code

```
import threading

cnt = 0
def fun_timer():
  global cnt
  cnt = cnt + 1
  print "hello", cnt

timer = threading.Timer(1., fun_timer)         
timer.start()

timer = threading.Timer(2., fun_timer)         
timer.start()
```

and it produces the following result

```
hello 1
hello 2
```

So it works as expected

Comment: In my case , it did not run twice